# Insights - No admin data found

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I am trying to add a website to insights and have successfully done so in the past.  However when I try to add, I receive a 'No admin data found at root webpage' error. I added '' to the root as instructed but insights is still unable to add the website.  There is no redirect of any kind.  The hosting is on earthlink.  This is the first time I've had the problem and the first time I have had a website on earthlink so I am not sure if the problem is related.

Comment: Please include a link to your page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Facebook Insights admin area. For me the fb:admins tag just wasn't showing on the screen. I had a dig around with Firebug and found the meta tag in the popup. The meta tag is built from your own Facebook ID.

eg.

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="12345678" />
```

A step by step guide can be found here http://mydevoncliffscaravan.co.uk/articles/how-to-get-facebook-insights-working-for-your-website.asp